# How does Box2D handle positions and coordinates?

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml

I'm playing around with SFML and Box2D, and in SFML a shape's position is defined by it's upper-left corner. Also, SFML handles coordinates based on the (0, 0) being the upper-left corner of the screen, and the x-axis extending to the right and the y-axis extending down.

So, I have two questions.

Does Box2D have a concept of the origin being somewhere specific (like the upper left corner or the center) or not since it's rendering agnostic?

I read somewhere that setting a body's position set's the object's *center* vs the upper-left corner like SFML. Is this true? For example:

```
b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
groundBodyDef.position.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);
```

Does this mean the body is centered at (0, -10) or that it's upper-left corner is at (0, -10)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Box2D handles positions and coordinates as if they were horizontal and vertical meters from a world's origin. In other words, a coordinate of say `b2Vec2(2.0f, 3.0f)` represents a point that's 2 meters to the right of the origin and 3 meters above the origin (assuming a visual representation of positive X to the right and positive Y to the top). Left and right and up and down are interchangeable as you point out given it's rendering agnostic but if you pair the `b2Vec2(2, 3)` coordinate with a gravity of `b2Vec2(0, -10)` and have the coordinate visually represented as described then a dynamic body will visually accelerate downward assuming there's nothing in the way to stop it.

Setting a body's position sets it's location relative to the world origin. It also provides an origin of sorts itself then for shapes that are associated with the body (via fixtures) since coordinates used for shapes are relative to it's associated body's position.

In answer to your last question, setting the `groundBodyDef` position to `(0.f, -10.0f)` means the body created with the `groundBodyDef` will be positioned at `(0.f, -10.0f)` and any shapes you attach to that body will be relative to that position. Thinking of it as a center doesn't seem wrong per se to me; at least no more wrong than thinking of a 2-D origin of (0, 0) as being the center of a graph. You might get in trouble with thinking in terms of a center though if you confuse position with center in terms of mass.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I've got it... If I'm correct, fixtures are attached to the *position*, basically making it the center?